# Is running an OLS a valid way of running a probit model?

Tags: regression, probit

I came across some models where the dependent variable (Y) and the independent variables (Xs) are transformed through a cumulative normal Φ function, then the modeler runs an OLS regression.

Is this a valid way to run a probit regression?

I thought the probit regression was run using Maximum Likelihood?

Comment: Are these analyses available online? I have used a similar method before (probit transform then fit a non-linear regression model). It would usually make more sense to fit via MLE but there could be a valid reason to not do this.

Comment: No this is private business documents (financial institution)

Comment: You mean it is argued that the following conventional procedure and the one discussed here? I would not see why that would be the case...
`library(AER)
attach(HMDA)
summary(glm(deny ~ pirat, family = binomial(link = "probit")))
summary(lm(pnorm(as.numeric(deny)-1)~pnorm(pirat)))` (The transformation in the second model gives 0s and 1s for the dependent variable.)

Comment: It would be difficult to conceive of any theoretical justification for this approach.  Sometimes, though, algorithms simply work even though they have no reason not to.  YMMV.

Comment: @ChristophHanck sorry I did not understand. Do you agree this approach is wrong or you think it is fine?

Comment: I agree with @whuber that I do see no theoretical justification for the approach nor does my little empirical example suggest there is one that I am not aware of (I also tried a little simulation at home that I could post tomorrow that also shows no signs of this being "correct" with additionally looking at the `margins` package which I tried to see if OLS on the transformed possibly identifies the same marginal effects as ML.